# Enabling asset pipeline for videos in middleman

Tags: ruby, asset-pipeline, middleman

In my middleman static site, my images, fonts and CSS are properly going through the asset pipeline, and getting their fingerprint suffix (`img/logo-3e4a3149.png` for example).

However, my mp4 files that reside in the `assets/vid` folder are just copied as is with the same name, which makes them stale (cache wise) when built and deployed.

How can additional asset types (mp4) be configured to be treated like images in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

The file extension '.mp4' is not considered as asset files by default, i.e. are not listed in [`asset_extensions`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/middleman/middleman/Middleman/Application#asset_extensions-instance_method).
Adding the file extension to the list fixes the issue (as you already figured out yourself).
Options to do so:

```rb
config[:asset_extensions] += %w[.mp4]

# or

config.asset_extensions += %w[.mp4]

# or

activate :asset_hash do |asset_hash|
  asset_hash.exts += %w[.mp4]
end

# or

# Passing `ext:` argument overrides list of file extensions!
activate :asset_hash, exts: %w[.css .png .jpg .jpeg .webp .svg .svgz .js .gif .ttf .otf .woff .woff2 .eot .ico .map .mp4]
```

Comment: Array concatenation `+= %w[.mp4]` can be replaced by pushing `<< '.mp4'` if only one element should be appended.

Answer (score 0):

Well, answering my own question, although I am not sure this is the approach intended by the developers.

1. Found the source code for the [`AssetHash`](https://github.com/middleman/middleman/blob/master/middleman-core/lib/middleman-core/extensions/asset_hash.rb#L7) extension, which provides some insight.
2. Found what seems to be an outdated [configuration documentation](https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/configuration#configuring-extensions) that happens to mention the `asset_hash` setting (although the mentioned syntax does not work).

So after fiddling with it, I came up with this in my `config.rb`

```rb
activate :asset_hash # this was always there
config.asset_extensions << ".mp4"
```

It seems a little dirty, since all other settings in the middleman config are elegantly set using the `set :something` DSL, but at least it works.

I also noticed that this syntax works:

```rb
activate :asset_hash, exts: [".mp4"]
```

but it replaces the factory settings.

If someone finds a better option, please share.